# How do I trigger a textbox with a button

Tags: java, button, textbox

I have the following code. How would I make a textbox displaying the text on each button come up when that button is pushed? I'm taking a beginning java class online that gives little to no instruction and then asks me to do stuff like this, so any and all help is very much appreciated. I want to learn! Thank You!

```
import java.awt.*;
public class FinalProj2 extends Frame
{
FinalProj2()
{
    setTitle("Buttons");
    setSize(600,600);
    show();
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Frame objFrame;
    Button objButton1;
    Button objButton2;
    Button objButton3;
    Label objLabel2;

    objFrame= new FinalProj2();
    objButton1= new Button("Submit");
    objButton2= new Button("Cancel");
    objButton3= new Button("What Now");
    objLabel2= new Label();


    objButton1.setBounds(60,200,80,80);
    objButton2.setBounds(150,300,80,80);
    objButton3.setBounds(60,400,80,80);


    objFrame.add(objButton2);
    objFrame.add(objButton1);
    objFrame.add(objButton3);
    objFrame.add(objLabel2);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Attach an ActionListener using `addActionListener()` method on each of the buttons instances you need. In `actionPerformed()`method text in textbox

```
btn.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       lbl.setText(btn.getLabel());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, You want that when you press any button then the button label should be displayed in [TextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)

For this you have to create an object of TextField like:

```
final TextField box = new TextField();
```

Then you can add ActionListener on that TextField like:

```
objButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   box.setText(objButton1.getLabel());
}
});
```

Same for other buttons.